# problema al filtrar un jtable en java con entorno netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, sqlite

mi problema es que filtro el jtable, y al seleccionar la fila eta se envia a unos textfile pero no es la fila que seleccione sino la primera, osea tengo 3 filas, filtro la 3 y cuando la selecciono es como si seleccionara la primera porque los datos que llegan al textfile son de la primera fila y no de la que filtre.

sin filtrar el jtable presiono una fila y efectivamenteme vota los datos ue son, pero cuando la filtro y dejo una sola fila, ahí es el problema.

MI CODIGO ES EL SIGUIENTE

```
    private void tblSeguimientoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    if(evt.getClickCount()==1){
        JTable receptor=(JTable)evt.getSource();
        txtID.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),0).toString());
        txtUsuario.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),1).toString());
        txtIdentificacion.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),2).toString());
        txtFecha.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),3).toString());
        txtCodificacion.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),4).toString());
        txaAnalisisDesc.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),5).toString());
        txaSeguimiento.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),6).toString());
        txaCompromiso.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),7).toString());
        txtRealizado.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),8).toString());
        txtValido.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),9).toString());
        txtNumeroSeguimiento.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),10).toString());
        txtCorreoInstitucional.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),11).toString());
        txtCelular.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),12).toString());
        txtAre.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),13).toString());
    }
```

y este es el otro

```
    txtFiltro.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {

            trs.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter( "(?i)" + txtFiltro.getText(),2,8,9,10,13));
        }

    });
    trs = new TableRowSorter(modelo);
    tblSeguimiento.setRowSorter(trs);
}
```

y este es el de traer los datos

```
     public void MostrarDatos(){
        conexion objConexion=new conexion();
        while(modelo.getRowCount()>0){
            modelo.removeRow(0);
        }
            try {
            ResultSet resultado=objConexion.consultarRegistros("SELECT * FROM Estudiantes");
            while (resultado.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("ID"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("Nombre"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("FechaNacimiento"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("Identificacion"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("Edad"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("Semestre"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("ContactoEmNombre"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("ContactoEmNumero"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("MotivoConsulta"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("AntecedentesPersonales"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("RemisionS"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("RemisionN"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("RemisionL"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("NombrePsicologa"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("Validacion"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("FechaActual"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("CorreoEstudiante"));  
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("Celular"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("Parentesco"));
                System.out.println(resultado.getString("Area"));

                Object[] oUsuario={resultado.getString("ID"),resultado.getString("Nombre"),resultado.getString("FechaNacimiento"),resultado.getString("Identificacion"),resultado.getString("Edad"),resultado.getString("Semestre"),resultado.getString("ContactoEmNombre"),resultado.getString("ContactoEmNumero"),resultado.getString("MotivoConsulta"),resultado.getString("AntecedentesPersonales"),resultado.getString("RemisionS"),resultado.getString("RemisionN"),resultado.getString("RemisionL"),resultado.getString("NombrePsicologa"),resultado.getString("Validacion"),resultado.getString("FechaActual"), resultado.getString("CorreoEstudiante"), resultado.getString("Celular"), resultado.getString("Parentesco"), resultado.getString("Area")};
                modelo.addRow(oUsuario);
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: me podrias explicar cual fue el cambio?